# How to type JSON in textarea using Selenium WebDriver and Java?

Tags: java, json, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver, we can type text in textarea using `sendKeys` like:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea")).sendKeys("text to type");
```

but in my case `text to type` is JSON something like:

```
{
    "name": "Enter Name",
    "id": "Enter ID",
    "helpText": "Enter Help Text"
}
```

If I want to type above JSON in textarea, I can store it in string and type it but I need to resolve escape character issues.

In this case, what could be the best solution to type JSON in textarea using JAVA?

Comment: get the text and assign it to `String var = text.replaceAll("\"","\\\"");` and then send it.

Answer (score 1):

U can try it out by the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920866/how-to-type-json-in-textarea-using-selenium-webdriver-and-java#comment44239758_27920866) I gave or you can use JavascriptExecutor to set value in textbox as:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) dw2;
    js.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagname('textarea')[0].value='"
        + <your json string> + "'");
```

Comment: @TDHM can u please confirm whether it worked? Or is there any other issue u r facing in this? Thanks.

Comment: Is the comma order for JS is correct in the snippet?